# Is there a way to handle Protractor's Expected conditions when they're not met other than try catch or promise reject

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, expected-condition

I'm using protractor to automate web tests along with the async/await pattern.

Suppose I have an element that only appears when it's the first time that I click on a specific toggle.

The issue is, when it does appear, I want to click on it.

Is there a way to wait for this element, and if it appears I click on it, if it doesn't, I click  on something else and then continue my operations without using a try/catch block

Si it should be something like this ( Please note that this is hypothetical):

```ts
/*This will click on the toggle that might trigger the extra element to appear*/
await this.toggle.click()
const isExtraElementPresent = await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(extraElement),2000);
if (isExtraElementPresent ){
    await extraElement.click();
}
```

What I'm doing now is the following:

```ts
await this.toggle.click();
try {
    await this.extraElement.click();
    }
catch (error) {
    await console.log("Extra element didn't appear.");
    }
```

Comment: I think the first snippet looks reasonable. Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

`try/catch` is the only way to handle this scenario.

```
try {
  // wait for the element
} catch (error) {
  // do whatever if the element is not present
}
```

But, you should consider to avoid it for the reason below

Your logic is as below

- login
- wait for the element for 2 sec which may not be present
- try clicking

Your second item takes 2 seconds in majority of login attempts, so often that its almost `browser.sleep`

The right pattern to follow would be like this

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var welcomeMessagePresent = EC.presenceOf(welcomeMessageElement);
var firstLoginPopupPresent = EC.presenceOf(firstLoginPopup);
// Waits for either condition
await browser.wait(
  EC.or(welcomeMessagePresent, firstLoginPopupPresent), 
  5000,
  'neither condition satisfied'
);
```

So it would wait for one of conditions. And there can be any number of conditions - 1,2,3... In your case it's either of the conditions